# conditional probability has binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $X_1, X_2$ be two independent random variables with $X_i \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)\,$ for $i=1,2$, where $\lambda>0$. Let $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq k \leq n$. Define $f(k):=\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k | X_2 + X_1 = n)$.
>
> I want to show that: $f$ is a binomial distribution.

My ideas: We have
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k | X_2 + X_1 = n)=\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k | X_2 = n-k)$$

By using that the independence of random variables, $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k | X_2 = n-k)=\mathbb{P}(X_2=n-k)=exp(- \lambda) \frac{\lambda^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}$$,
hence it suffices to find $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n',k'\in \mathbb{N}:exp(- \lambda) \frac{\lambda^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}=\frac{n'!}{k'! (n'-k')! p^{k'} (1-p)^{n'-k'}}$

In other words to find a appropriate binomial distribution given by $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n',k'\in \mathbb{N}$.

I really can't see how to manipulate the terms to find such binomial distribution. Is there another less technical approach?

Thanks for the help.

Bests

bjn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps easier with $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k , X_1+X_2 = n)=\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k , X_2 = n-k) $$ $$ =\exp(- \lambda) \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}\exp(- \lambda) \frac{\lambda^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} = \exp(−2\lambda)\frac{(2\lambda)^n}{n!} {n \choose k}\frac1{2^n}$$ 
using that the independence, so $$\mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2 = n)=\sum_k \mathbb{P}(X_1 = k , X_1+X_2 = n)=\exp(−2\lambda)\frac{(2\lambda)^n}{n!} $$ and thus $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k \mid X_1+X_2 = n) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k , X_1+X_2 = n)}{\mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2 = n)} ={n \choose k}\frac1{2^n}$$ which is binomial, all assuming $0 \le k \le n$.

Comment: Thanks. Is also $$\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=k | \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i})$$ binomial distributed? I could derive the formula $$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{m}{X_{i}}=n)=exp(-m\lambda) \frac{{m\lambda}^{n}}{n!}$$. By doing similiarly as you,  I get $$\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=k | \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i})= \binom nk \frac{(m-1)^{n-k}}{m^n}$$

It seems to me it doesn't look like binomial distributed. Is that correct?

Comment: You have swapped $m$ and $n$ on the left hand side. Your final expression should be $$\displaystyle \mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=k  \mid \sum_{i=1}^{m} X_{i}=n\right)= \binom nk \frac{(m-1)^{n-k}}{m^n} = \binom nk p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$ which is the distribution of a binomial random variable with $p=\frac1m$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I memorized the wrong formula for the binomial distribution.